# How to click views behind a Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, material-design, android-toolbar

I have a toolbar with a transparent/translucent background that overlays the content. So, behind the toolbar, views can appear that are clickable. The problem is that they can not be clicked through the toolbar because the toolbar is catching the click event.

I tried setting `android:clickable="false"`, `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` for the toolbar, but it has no effect. How can I send a click through the toolbar to the underlying view?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Take a look at the implementation of `Toolbar`. It *eats touch events*, regardless of the `clickable` attribute.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Toolbars always eat touch events, but should still respect the touch event dispatch
    // contract. If the normal View implementation doesn't want the events, we'll just silently
    // eat the rest of the gesture without reporting the events to the default implementation
    // since that's what it expects.

    final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);
    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        mEatingTouch = false;
    }

    if (!mEatingTouch) {
        final boolean handled = super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && !handled) {
            mEatingTouch = true;
        }
    }

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
        mEatingTouch = false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The solution is to extend from `Toolbar` and override `onTouchEvent`.

```
public class NonClickableToolbar extends Toolbar {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Toolbar consumes all clicks. You need to subclass Toolbar, like @Matthias Robbens already mentioned.

If you still want to be able to set a click listener on the toolbar, use this:

```
/** Do not eat touch events, like super does. Instead map an ACTION_DOWN to a click on this 
 * view. If no click listener is set (default), we do not consume the click */
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN){
        return performClick();
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Easier answer would be just :

```
toolbarV?.isClickable = false
toolbarV?.isFocusable = false
```

Answer (score -10):

Your design needs to be adjusted. You cannot provide clickable views behind a transparent/translucent toolbar. You need to provide a top padding equal to the height of the toolbar and/or implement the quick return pattern for the toolbar.