# Inside CollapsingToolbarLayout ImageView Click event is not trigger Android

Tags: android

Image View inside CollapsingToolbarLayout , but click event is not triggering.
How to to solve this issue.

Comment: have you solved your problem?

Comment: Stuck at the same problem. Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Just make sure you don't have any view above the layout. In my case I had a toolbar and it was eating the clicks.

```
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        >

        <include...
            />
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar...
            />
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout...
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

I had to create a new Class extending toolbar that let clicks go through it([How to click views behind a Toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425786/how-to-click-views-behind-a-toolbar))

```
public class NonClickableToolbar extends Toolbar {

    @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: "In my case I had a toolbar and it was eating the clicks." That helped, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Question is not elaborate enough, but looks like ImageView is consuming your click event.

try using

```
ImageView.setOnClickListener(null);
```

CollapsingToolbarLayout should get the click events. if this doesn't work, you know on what line to Google for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this XML attribute

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to your CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: Facing the same problem. This didn't solve it. Have you faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I happened to drop by this problem too. It seems clicks in the area of the toolbar/appbar do not trigger.

If your UI/UX allows, try placing the `ImageView` outside the area of the toolbar. For example, try placing it aligned to parent bottom. The click should hopefully be triggered. Worked for me (I was working with an `ImageButton` though, but pretty sure `ImageView` should also work).

Answer (score 0):

You can put the ImageView outside collapsing toolbar. I was facing the same issue. Solved it by placing the view outside collapsing toolbar and anchoring it accordingly.