# Letting touch events go to the view pager behind collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, android-viewpager, onclicklistener, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a view pager nested inside a collapsing toolbar. I want to detect when that view pager is clicked. I am trying to add a simple onclick listener but it doesn't work. However I am able to swipe through the view pager. Below is the layout code :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager_introduction"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            tools:listitem="@layout/pager_item"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:clickable="true"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/detail_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"


        // Some code


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewPagerCountDots"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/item_detail_container"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar consumes clicks, so you will have to subclass it. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47267740/923557) for a way to do that.
Apart from toolbar, the other views in your layout may consume clicks in a similar way